# How to open this plastic cap?

Tags: alcohol, containers

How do I open this cap? It is from a bottle of Bombay gin.

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: you could use a clean screwdriver to pop the plastic pouring cap off.

Comment: @Max the handle of a sturdy teaspoon is what I normally use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to open it.  That's a slow-pouring cap, you should just be able to pour out of it.  If you can't, that's because it's broken somehow.

Comment: FuzzyChef is correct. But those things annoy me too. They are not *designed* to be taken out. I have done what @Max mentioned but you do risk getting shards of plastic in your bottle. So you may need a strainer, bowl and funnel once you have broken the slow pouring cap out of the bottle.

Comment: usually the plastic thingamabob just pops out. (obviously, if I feel it does not, I will not risk breaking the bottle)

Comment: rip it out with needle nose pliers if you don't want it :)

Comment: @SteveChambers I've mainly come across these in vinegar, oil etc. rather than alcohol, but they're normal rather soft plastic that shouldn't break and would take a lot of force to tear.

Comment: @ChrisH the ones in alcohol bottles are usually made from a hard brittle plastic.  No idea why.

Comment: I obviously don't drink enough! I don't think there's a single one on my shelf of barely-touched spirits.  I wonder if the plasticisers in the  soft ones aren't compatible with long-term contact with alcohol, though I'd expect oil to have similar issues if so